# Change syntax event listener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon

I've written some code in Javascript which needs some transformation but I don't know how to achieve this.

my code :

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {...}), false);
```

into

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {myExtension.init()}, false);
```

The key here is to pass the argument e. I've tried "function(e)" and "myExtension.init(e)" but it doesn't work.

EDIT (all my code - the function code is located at the end of the code):

```
var myExt_urlBarListener = {
  QueryInterface: function(aIID)
  {
   if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
       aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
       aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))
     return this;
   throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
  },

  onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI)
  {
    myExtension.processNewURL(aURI);
  },

  onStateChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
  onProgressChange: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {},
  onStatusChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
  onSecurityChange: function(a, b, c) {}
};

var myExtension = {
  oldURL: null,

  init: function(e) {
    // Listen for webpage loads

    gBrowser.addProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener,
        Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION);
  },

  uninit: function(e) {
    gBrowser.removeProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener);
  },

  processNewURL: function(aURI) {
    if (aURI.spec == this.oldURL)
      return;

    // now we know the url is new...
    this.oldURL = aURI.spec;

    var href = aURI.spec;

    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    if(vars[0].match(/^http:\/\/www\.google\.fr/))
    {
        //I want use the event e here
        //But it doesn't work
        displayBookmarks(e);
    }
  }
};

//The following doesn't work (I get "e is not defined" in the Error Console) 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {myExtension.init(e)}, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {myExtension.uninit()}, false);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "transform"?

Comment: Then something else is wrong. `function(e) {myExtension.init(e)}` is definitely correct (if you want to pass the event object). What is `window` in this case? The browser window or the a page's window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add the parameter in the function declaration as well:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {myExtension.init(e)}, false);
...
init: function(e) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried it and it doesn't work (I still get "e is not defined" in the Error Console).

Comment: @Bruno: Then you either didn't change declaration of `myExtension.init` as explained above or you are trying to access variable `e` from a different function (one where it isn't declared). Either way, Error Console is your friend - it will point you to the exact line in code where the error happens, look around.